# How to fix abrupt start to audio

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I am using rpi4b with raspbian dated dec 2020 and seeed respeaker mic hat 2 and notice there is an abrupt start followed by some silence to the audio.

Here is a sample with a simple test `arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f S16_LE -r16000 file.wav`

[image: image.png]

I have tried applying some filters using ladspa (delay and fadein) and other alsa configurations without success.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Raspberry Pi OS 2021-01-11](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/). As stated in the [Release notes](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/release_notes.txt) there are some important bug fixes belonging to audio.

Comment: not quite, still shows, here are two tests [image.png](https://postimg.cc/v10wFmvF)